# Entity framework validation for decimal type. Can't validate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Try with comma:

> The field Sum must be a number.

Try with dot:

> The value '123.5' is not valid for Sum

Model:

```
public decimal Sum { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sum, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

May be something wrong with Culture?

Comment: @Dai sounds like neither worked